# CSS blur on background image but not on content

Tags: css, background-image, blur

I did [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jLGFp/).

I'm trying to blur the background image, but the main content is blurred too (the `<span>`)

How can I blur the background without blurring the content?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could overlay one element above the blurred element like so

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jLGFp/3/)

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
}
p {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry i cn't use absolute on div :(

Comment: You could blur the background image in photoshop prior to uploading it, Otherwise you will need to use javascript. There is currently no way of blurring a div without it's contents also becoming blurred with CSS only. Overlaying them is the only way unfortunately. `blur.js` is good for this kind of thing.

Comment: sorry i unaccepted since on firefox it doesn't works http://jsfiddle.net/jLGFp/3/

Comment: You didn't state you need firefox support in your question. Unless stated otherwise, the question it is assumed the method will only work in supported browsers. For firefox support `blur` is not possible. You will need to use an `svg` which is a different question really. It is covered here http://css-plus.com/2010/05/how-to-add-a-gaussian-blur-effect-to-elements-within-firefox/.

Answer (score 27):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockes/fpbpd86d/)

```
.blur-bgimage {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.blur-bgimage:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width : 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: -1;

    filter        : blur(10px);
    -moz-filter   : blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter     : blur(10px);

    transition        : all 2s linear;
    -moz-transition   : all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    -o-transition     : all 2s linear;
}
```

You can blur the body background image by using the body's :before pseudo class to inherit the image and then blurring it. Wrap all that into a class and use javascript to add and remove the class to blur and unblur.

Comment: What is :before doing, exactly? I see that without :before the filters are applied to the whole content as well. I understand that, but why is :before preventing this?

Comment: @aless80 `:before` is prepended to selected items (while `:after` is appended). Main difference from direct children of items is that `:before` and `:after` are accessed only through CSS and `content` property is mandatory for them to display.

Comment: :before and :after are pseudo-elements. If you write `.blur-bgimage:before {..}` you're creating a new child-element for `.blur-bgimage` called `::before`. Because it is one of the children of `.blur-bgimage` its properties (e.g. `filter: blur(10px)`) are independent of other siblings.

Answer (score 11):

Add another `div` or `img` to your main `div` and blur that instead. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLGFp/1/)

```
.blur {
    background:url('http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/051/726/17-i-lol.jpg?1318992465') no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-filter: blur(13px);
    -moz-filter: blur(13px);
    -o-filter: blur(13px);
    -ms-filter: blur(13px);
    filter: blur(13px);
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: But this creates a scroll in the page :(

Answer (score 8):

## `backdrop-filter`

Unfortunately Mozilla has really dropped the ball and taken it's time with the feature. I'm personally hoping it makes it in to the next Firefox ESR as that is what the next major version of Waterfox will use.

MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Mozilla implementation: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1178765

From the MDN documentation page:

```
/* URL to SVG filter */
backdrop-filter: url(commonfilters.svg#filter);

/* <filter-function> values */
backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
backdrop-filter: brightness(60%);
backdrop-filter: contrast(40%);
backdrop-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 10px blue);
backdrop-filter: grayscale(30%);
backdrop-filter: hue-rotate(120deg);
backdrop-filter: invert(70%);
backdrop-filter: opacity(20%);
backdrop-filter: sepia(90%);
backdrop-filter: saturate(80%);

/* Multiple filters */
backdrop-filter: url(filters.svg#filter) blur(4px) saturate(150%);
```

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is the "backdrop-filter" property instead of just "filter".

Example:

backdrop-filter: blur(5px); ✔️

filter: blur(5px); ❌

Answer (score 2):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLGFp/34/).

```
<div> 
    <img class="class" src="http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/051/726/17-i-lol.jpg?1318992465">
    </img>
    <span>
        Hello World!
    </span>
</div>
```

What about this? No absolute positioning on div, but instead on img and span.

Comment: Apologies, this is basically what @TreeTree said, forgot to scroll down.

Comment: Shouldn't `img` be a single tag?