# how to blur the background of the text while using bootstrap css file?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, blur

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/ and as you can see, I use here extended resource - bootstrap.min.css. So far the page looks like in the result of this fiddle. I would like to change it so the darker background is blurred (exactly like in this tutorial http://jordanhollinger.com/2014/01/29/css-gaussian-blur-behind-a-translucent-box/ ). Is it possible without modifing the bootstrap css file?
I tried to replace this line:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
```

with what they suggest on this tutorial:

```
#black{

   -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: url('/media/blur.svg#blur');
    filter: blur(10px);
}
#black p, #black h1{
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px
}
```

but all I get is blurred text: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/1/

could you help me with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS blur on background image but not on content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411257/css-blur-on-background-image-but-not-on-content)

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need a blank "background" `div` that matches the width/position/etc of the content you want it on using the `blur` property and `z-index: -1;`.  For example, say I had a box that was 300px wide and 100px tall.  I'd have to make a #blurredbackground div that matches that same width, height, and position with `filter: blur` and `z-index: -1` added.

HTML:

```
<div id="blurredbackground></div>
<div id="content">
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 72px; left: 72px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}    

#blurredbackground {
    position: absolute;    /*matches #content position*/
    bottom: 72px; left: 72px;    /*matches #content position*/
    width: 300px;    /*matches #content width*/
    height: 100px;    /*matches #content height*/
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: thank you, could you help me with edditing my fiddle? I tried to do so and all I got is this http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/4/

Comment: thanks, that gives me some ideas, I just have some problems with including that into my bootstrap framework..

Comment: Please select as answer if it helped :D

Comment: it helped, but only partialy :( I still struggle with blurring the element in my html code (that uses bootstrap), I know now thanks to you how to do it on plain html code, but I can't figure out how to do it on my existing one :( so maybe someone at some point will be able to help me with that..

Comment: @randomuser1 just use the inspect view and see whether every css modification above has been actually applied and not overwritten.